# Update prepared statement form with validation

Tags: php, mysqli

Thank you in advance for taking your time to look at my question.
I have the code below for update a prepared statement form with validation & sensitization. When I try the code without my validation & sensitization, the updating form works perfectly, however when I add my filter-has-var then my code doesn't work and give me an error. I know that problem is the related to the place that I should put my validation condition but I don't know where and how to fix it. 
Please help!

```
<?php
$missing = null;
$errors = null;
require_once('../includes/connection.inc.php');
// initialize flags
$OK = false;
$done = false;
// create database connection
$conn = dbConnect('write');
// initialize statement
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
// get details of selected record
if (isset($_GET['article_id']) && !$_POST) {
    // prepare SQL query
    $sql = 'SELECT article_id, title, article
    FROM blog WHERE article_id = ?';
    if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
        // bind the query parameter
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['article_id']);
        // bind the results to variables
        $stmt->bind_result($article_id, $title, $article);
        // execute the query, and fetch the result
        $OK = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->fetch();
    }
}

// if form has been submitted, update record
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'update')) {
    try {
        require_once './Validator.php';
        $required = array('title', 'comment');
        $val = new Pos_Validator($required);
        $val->checkTextLength('title', 3);
        $val->removeTags('title');
        $val->checkTextLength('article', 0, 150);
        $val->useEntities('article');
        $filtered = $val->validateInput();
        $missing = $val->getMissing();
        $errors = $val->getErrors();

        if (!$errors) {
            // prepare update query
            $sql = 'UPDATE blog SET title = ?, article = ?
            WHERE article_id = ?';
            if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
                $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $_POST['title'], $_POST['article'],
                    $_POST['article_id']);
                $done = $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
        // redirect if $_GET['article_id'] not defined
        if ($done || !isset($_GET['article_id'])) {
            header('Location: http://localhost/phpsols/admin/blog_list_mysqli.php');
            exit;
        }
        // store error message if query fails
        if (isset($stmt) && !$OK && !$done) {
            $error = $stmt->error;
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Update Blog Entry</title>
    <link href="../styles/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Update Blog Entry</h1>
    <p><a href="blog_list_mysqli.php">List all entries </a></p>
    <?php 
    if (isset($error)) {
        echo "<p class='warning'>Error: $error</p>";
    }
    if($article_id == 0) { ?>
    <p class="warning">Invalid request: record does not exist.</p>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
        <p>
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input name="title" type="text" class="widebox" id="title"  
            value="<?php  echo htmlentities($title, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="article">Article:</label>
            <textarea name="article" cols="60" rows="8" class="widebox"   
            id="article"><?php echo htmlentities($article,
            ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');?></textarea>   
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Entry" id="update">
            <input name="article_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $article_id;    
            ?>">
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `and give me an error`. So do you plan on sharing that error message, or do you expect us to guess?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your code is not very readable - but from what I can see, you have a `}` too much in front of your `catch`:

```
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
 }
 }
```

should probably be

```
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You were right, I have fixed it but it is still giving me an error.

Comment: Which error? Could you update your question with the error message, please?

Comment: It is giving me the following errors on each of the box forms and doesn't update the database: Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: title <b> or Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: article <b>

Comment: You are checking `if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'insert')) {`, but I can't see an input element with the name `insert` in your HTML form.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it should be update instead of insert but when I change insert to update it is still not working when I am missing the required filed and it is telling me article-id is not defined and Error.

Comment: You are checking for $_GET['article_id'], but the form is submitted with a POST request.

Comment: Yes, I have modified it but doesn't make a difference in my errors.